# angular ng serve --open cannot run

Tags: angular

ng serve --open can run the first application successfully, but when I create another project and try to run it. it shows the following error message.

**ERROR** in TypeError:

```
Cannot read property 'flags' of undefined**
    at resolveAlias (C:\Users\780892\Desktop\fourth semester 2\emerging\angular\demo2\node_modules\typescript\lib\typescript.js:36513:37)
    at checkAliasSymbol (C:\Users\780892\Desktop\fourth semester 2\emerging\angular\demo2\node_modules\typescript\lib\typescript.js:64502:26)
    at checkImportBinding (C:\Users\780892\Desktop\fourth semester 2\emerging\angular\demo2\node_modules\typescript\lib\typescript.js:64534:13)
    at checkImportDeclaration (C:\Users\780892\Desktop\fourth semester 2\emerging\angular\demo2\node_modules\typescript\lib\typescript.js:64552:29)
    at checkSourceElementWorker (C:\Users\780892\Desktop\fourth semester 2\emerging\angular\demo2\node_modules\typescript\lib\typescript.js:64961:28)
    at checkSourceElement (C:\Users\780892\Desktop\fourth semester 2\emerging\angular\demo2\node_modules\typescript\lib\typescript.js:64800:17)
    at Object.forEach (C:\Users\780892\Desktop\fourth semester 2\emerging\angular\demo2\node_modules\typescript\lib\typescript.js:317:30)
    at checkSourceFileWorker (C:\Users\780892\Desktop\fourth semester 2\emerging\angular\demo2\node_modules\typescript\lib\typescript.js:65123:20)
    at checkSourceFile (C:\Users\780892\Desktop\fourth semester 2\emerging\angular\demo2\node_modules\typescript\lib\typescript.js:65091:13)
    at getDiagnosticsWorker (C:\Users\780892\Desktop\fourth semester 2\emerging\angular\demo2\node_modules\typescript\lib\typescript.js:65179:17)
    at Object.getDiagnostics (C:\Users\780892\Desktop\fourth semester 2\emerging\angular\demo2\node_modules\typescript\lib\typescript.js:65165:24)
    at C:\Users\780892\Desktop\fourth semester 2\emerging\angular\demo2\node_modules\typescript\lib\typescript.js:98703:85
    at runWithCancellationToken (C:\Users\780892\Desktop\fourth semester 2\emerging\angular\demo2\node_modules\typescript\lib\typescript.js:98665:24)
    at getBindAndCheckDiagnosticsForFileNoCache (C:\Users\780892\Desktop\fourth semester 2\emerging\angular\demo2\node_modules\typescript\lib\typescript.js:98691:20)
    at getAndCacheDiagnostics (C:\Users\780892\Desktop\fourth semester 2\emerging\angular\demo2\node_modules\typescript\lib\typescript.js:98956:26)
    at getBindAndCheckDiagnosticsForFile (C:\Users\780892\Desktop\fourth semester 2\emerging\angular\demo2\node_modules\typescript\lib\typescript.js:98688:20)
```

*** Angular Live Development Server is listening on localhost:4200, open your browser on http://localhost:4200/ ***

I searched online, and I still cannot solve this problem. Could someone help me? thanks

Comment: I'm having the same issue at the moment -- when just 2 days ago it was working perfectly. Can't seem to create a new angular app and run it because of this error. I tried building and running the ones I created just 2 days ago, and it's compiling perfectly. Note that not much has been added to it, just bootstrap jquery and popper.js. But this error occurs on freshly created app by the angular CLI.

Answer (score 0):

it seems 9.1.4 bug, try

```
ng --version
```

downgrade in your `package.json` Angular related packages from 9.1.4 to 9.1.3

delete `package-lock.json` and `node_modules` and reinstall

```
npm install
```

Answer (score 0):

Seems to be a bug on Angular v**9.1.5**. You can verify it by `ng --version`.

```
Angular CLI: 9.1.4
Node: 12.16.3
OS: win32 x64

Angular: 9.1.5 ←--
... animations, common, compiler, compiler-cli, core, forms
... language-service, platform-browser, platform-browser-dynamic
... router
Ivy Workspace: Yes

Package                           Version
-----------------------------------------------------------
@angular-devkit/architect         0.901.4
@angular-devkit/build-angular     0.901.4
@angular-devkit/build-optimizer   0.901.4
@angular-devkit/build-webpack     0.901.4
@angular-devkit/core              9.1.4
@angular-devkit/schematics        9.1.4
@angular/cli                      9.1.4
```

To fix it, you can either edit your *package.json* and change all angular modules' version to `9.1.4` (remove the `~` before the version number) to downgrade, then run `npm install`.

OR run:

```
npm install @angular/core@9.1.4 @angular/animations@9.1.4 @angular/common@9.1.4 @angular/forms@9.1.4 @angular/platform-browser@9.1.4 @angular/router@9.1.4 @angular/platform-browser-dynamic@9.1.4 @angular/compiler@9.1.4 @angular/compiler-cli@9.1.4 @angular/language-service@9.1.4
```

then do `ng build` or `ng serve`.

Hope this works for you.

--

Cheers,
Kai

Comment: @Isabel Great to hear! :) By the way, this has now been fixed in v9.1.6. And if it's no trouble kindly mark as the answer if this is what worked for you. Cheers!